# How can I secure my plugin so only paying users can use it?

Tags: php, wordpress, code-access-security, api-key

I'm developing some (wordpress) plugins and I'm planning to have a license fee for whoever want's to use it.

Therefor I need a way to make sure that this plugin is not uploaded to a server where anyone can download it and use it for free.

So I was thinking of using an API key. Valid API key = user can use the plugin. Invalid = plugin does not work.

I've looked at this post [PHP API Key Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448455/php-api-key-generator) but I don't get much wiser of that.

I also know that since it's PHP, anyone can go into the code and disable API check (I'm just guessing)

What is the best way to secure my plugin? API key? Other ways? Does anyone have link to any good tutorials on the subject?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your plugin *relies upon* interaction with your own server an API key is an excellent way to prevent non-paying users from using it.
However if it doesn't need to interact with your server then anyone with a little PHP knowledge can modify your plugin to remove the API key check.

A major issue here is the licensing for your plugin. WordPress is GPL, and the GPL has a clause which requires 'derivative works' to also be licensed under the GPL. (That's an understatement: in fact, the whole GPL is based around that clause and wouldn't really work without it.)
There is a lot of argument about whether a plugin can be considered to be a 'derivative work'. In my opinion it isn't, and I think it is unethical to try to force it to be seen as one. However Automattic, the core WordPress devs, and the Free Software Foundation (the organisation which wrote the GPL) claim that WordPress plugins are legally bound to use the GPL and may not use another license.
So far there have been no court cases and so there is no precedent, but there is considerable animosity surrounding a couple of major WordPress plugins which don't use the GPL, and Automattic has basically threatened legal action whilst the plugin developer has said "please sue me". Not exactly a pretty situation, and I would say that regardless of the morality of the situation the fact is that the negative publicity normally outweighs the benefits of closed-sourcing a plugin.

To summarise: your plugin basically has to be GPL, which means you have to provide unencrypted source code, so anyone can modify your plugin to remove any restrictions you add. But it should be easy for you to talk most of your potential customers into wanting to buy the plugin from you instead of using a forked version - you can offer benefits such as support, upgrades, etc etc which probably won't be available for a "cracked" version.

There are several companies which successfully sell plugins, under the GPL and with no protection (API key etc). Even though anyone could *in theory* just download the plugin and upload it to a public site from which anyone could download it, *in practice* nobody wants to use an unofficial version which won't necessarily be updated for new versions of WordPress. So selling plugins does seem to be a viable business model even without protection of any kind.

Of course, all this assumes that someone doesn't just fork your plugin and carry on maintaining the codebase separately. There's not much you can do about that - but it's unlikely to happen.

For what it's worth, if you're trying to make life hard for someone who decides to redistribute your plugin, you may like to consider the following :

- you can still claim trademark rights on the name of your plugin even if the plugin itself is open source, so you can legally prevent them from using the same name which your customers know
- only the PHP code in a plugin has to be GPL'ed - you can distribute any files which don't contain PHP which interacts with WordPress under a separate license to forbid redistribution. For example, CSS, JavaScript, and images don't have to be under the GPL.

Comment: Yes, it will interact with my server. So API key looks like the way to go. Hmm... I don't think I like Automattic policy on plugins. So basically I can take the `Akismet` plugin, do some modifications to it, and voila - I have my own Akismet plugin which I can charge customers for using. Maybe I should do just that, and see how Autmattic like their own medicine.

Comment: PS. Do you have any links to guides / tutorials on how to implement API keys?

Comment: That's absolutely right; since the Akismet plugin is under the GPL you have the right to redistribute it, either as-is or in modified form. I don't think Automattic would actually mind that, since their whole business model is built around GPL'ed code. (I approve of that, but I do think it is unethical for them to try to force plugin authors into using the GPL just because their code calls WordPress functions.) 
But note that the Akismet plugin relies entirely on interaction with Automattic's servers, so you'd have to replace that service too - that's the hard part!

Comment: No, I don't know of any tutorials on implementing API keys. The plugin part would be easy; the server part would depend very much on what other interaction with your server was involved.

Comment: FYI, the WordPress.org website states (wordpress.org/about/license) that `There is some legal grey area regarding what is considered a derivative work, but we feel strongly that plugins and themes are derivative work and thus inherit the GPL license. If you disagree, you might want to consider a non-GPL platform such as Serendipity (BSD license) or Habari (Apache license) instead.`

Comment: Having been researching this for days, I am no more sure of anything and more confused about everything. WordPress is GPL, EVERYTHING that is for WP is a derivative work? That doesn't make sense (to me). One doesn't do something without the other, one won't work without the other. Each have their own IP. But anyway, so if no PHP can be sold, then how do Automattic get away with their licensing/subscriptions for WooCommerce? You're not just paying for the updates, you're paying for the software. You can't download it without paying for it. All their videos talk about BUYING the software.

Answer (score 6):

A great article can be found here, although this doesn't cover technique just somethings to bare in mind before you pursue the route much further
http://www.littlehart.net/atthekeyboard/2007/07/20/protecting-your-php-code/

Although for a more direct answer to your question, use an API key system and then encode your PHP using something along the lines of Zend Guard, so the user can't just go in and remove the API key check as the code is encoded.

Answer (score 5):

Using an API key is probably fine. You can't worry about people pirating your plugin, because it will happen no matter what you do. Someone with the knowledge to remove your API check is smart enough to remove any kind of protection you put in your script. You can't worry about these people.

Using products like Zend Guard isn't an option. It requires the end user to have Zend Optimizer installed on their system, and you can't guarantee that.

All that being said, you can't obfuscate or otherwise hide your source code anyway. Wordpress is licensed under the GPL license, and they strictly forbid plugins from having any other license. While you can sell the plugin, you can't hide the source code.

Comment: Agree! I would add in my comments something along the lines of: "If you bypass the API call know that you are acting unethically, preventing me from being compensated for the work you are about to benefit from, and preventing me from supporting myself from my labors. If you think it's too expensive, contact me, I'm sure we can work out something."

Answer (score 1):

to be honest, i don't think there is a bullet proof to avoid your plugin to get nulled, look at WProbot, they have a pretty solid way to validate licensing but still there are hundreds of nulled versions.

as long as people have to download your code someone will get his hands into it and nulled it, what you can do is offer a fremium version like s2member and AllinOneSEO pack does.

Answer (score -1):

I'm really thinking about these.
But It'S GPL and we cannot hide our codes.
I think, we have to do more complicated to read api key system. I'm thinking to do this. But there is a way to crack this with remove if else system unfortunetly if it's open source. You could look for example this:
[PHP AES encrypt / decrypt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422759/php-aes-encrypt-decrypt)